# Propiedad length considera como valor a empty en array

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente script que al realizar un check ingresa el registro a un array (validando su duplicidad) y cuando se quita el check elimina el registro del array(aquí tengo inconvenientes) cuando quita el array lo deja en vacío y el length lo considera como un valor.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var Lista = [];
        var Fila_r = {};
        let count = 0;

        function Items_Migrar_OC(CO_EMPR, TI_REQI, NU_REQI, NU_SECU, CO_ITEM, CA_SOLI, CA_ATEN, CA_PEND, Item_Seleccionado) {
            //alert(Item_Seleccionado);

            var duplicado = false;

            Fila_r = { CO_EMPR, TI_REQI, NU_REQI, NU_SECU, CO_ITEM, CA_SOLI, CA_ATEN, CA_PEND }

            if (Item_Seleccionado == "1") {

                //Si no es vacío verifica con función duplicado
                if (Lista != null){
                    duplicado = validateUnique(Fila_r)
                    //alert(duplicado);
                }

                // Si no existe ingresa datos al array
                if (duplicado == false) {
                    Lista[count] = Fila_r
                    count++;
                }
            }
            else {
                Lista = Lista.filter(function (elemento) {
                    return elemento.NU_SECU != Fila_r.NU_SECU
                });
            }

            console.log(Lista);
        }

        function validateUnique(myObject) {
            return !!Lista.find(i => i.NU_SECU === myObject.NU_SECU)
        }
    </script>
```

Interfaz de grilla con check:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Array construido considerando empty (en realidad necesito la cantidad de datos almacenados que no sean empty) para posteriormente realizar un blucle con la cantidad de registros - fila en el array:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Como borras los valores?

Comment: https://playcode.io/394553?tabs=script.js,preview,console ando probado tu codigo aqui y si me lo borra si tengo 3 y despues iteseleccionado es diferente de 1 lo remueve, podrias checarlo y decirme si asi esta bien

Comment: El codigo de Edgar Vazques creo que funciona bien para lo que necesitas, no serà que no te borra bien los valores por que agregaste un doble "!" al momento de return en la funcion validateUnique? ("!!").

Comment: Buenas, aquí envío el link del inconveniente exacto: https://playcode.io/398069?tabs=preview,console

Answer (score 0):

Cuando indicas una posición al insertar un elemento a un array, esta queda fija. Las claves de los arrays en javascript son siempre 0,1,2,3 etc. no pueden existir huecos, hay exepciones pero es mas largo de explicar.
El problema básicamente es el `count`, estas insertando en el array con la posicion fija, deberías usar push (para agregar al final) o unshift para agregar al principio (O [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/splice) para agregar en el medio). Eso hace que cambie las claves automáticamente. Es decir: cuando haces `Lista[count] = Fila_r` deberías hacer `Lista.push(Fila_r)`. Ejemplo fijando la posición:

```js
let array = [];

array[0] = "algo";
array[1] = "algo2";//vamos a eliminar este
array[2] = "algo3";

array.splice(1,1);

array[3] = "algo4";

console.log(array);
```

Ejemplo usando push:

```js
const array = [];

array.push("algo");
array.push("algo2");//Eliminamos este

array.splice(1,1);

array.push("algo3");

console.log(array)
```